# knockout mapper doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I went through lot of knockout articles but I'm failing to mapped below json object to knockout view model

```
{
   "VehicleModels":[
      {
         "Name":"Model 1",
         "Model":{
            "MakeName":"Ford"
         },
         "Styles":[
            {
               "StockImage":"http://google.com"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":"Model 2",
         "Model":{
            "MakeName":"Ford"
         },
         "Styles":[
            {
               "StockImage":"http://bing.com"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

this is my jsfiddle code [jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/369)

Comment: Please add the relevant mapping code and the markup

Comment: Also post your implementation of the mapping plugin

Comment: this is my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/369/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've updated the fiddle:

Essentially:

```
var mapping = {
    'Styles': {
        create: function (options) { // I fiddled with this, play around with it
            var self = options.data;
                self.stockimage = ko.observable();
                return self;
        }
    }
};

var data = {"VehicleModels":[{"Name":"Model 1","Model":{"MakeName":"Ford"},"Styles":[{"StockImage":"http://google.com"}]},{"Name":"Model 2","Model":{"MakeName":"Ford"},"Styles":[{"StockImage":"http://bing.com"}]}]};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping); // Here you did not need to put this as the 3rd parameter

ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // you need to apply the bindings at some point
```

And finally, you've tried to specify a value to a span:

```
<span data-bind='value: Name' />
```

Spans don't have values I think you wanted text:

```
<span data-bind='text: Name' />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i still can not mapped styles array to html view http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/430/ if you can please help me